# How can a mobx store react to observables of another mobx store?

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm starting out with mobx and react-native, and trying to split a big giant store into a bunch of smaller ones. What's the right way to imperatively run something in one store, based on @observables / @computed of one or more other stores? I tried this, and while the autorun works properly if depending on an @observable in AppStore, it stops working when it depends on an @observable from AuthStore.

```
class AuthStore {
  @observable loggedIn = false
}

class AppStore {
  constructor(authStore) {
    this.authStore = authStore
  }

  initialize = autorun(() => {
    if (this.authStore && this.authStore.loggedIn) {
      console.log("Do some work now that we're signed in...")
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect it's not working because the autorun is getting initialized before the other store has been instantiated? What's the right pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized that I can fix the above example, by moving the definition of initialize to the constructor, like this:

```
constructor(authStore) {
  this.authStore = authStore
  this.initialize = autorun(() => {
    if (this.authStore.loggedIn) {
      console.log("Do some work now that we're signed in...")
    }
  }
}
```

Still, I wonder is this the right approach? Or is there a better pattern for this sort of thing?

Comment: `autorun()` returns the disposer of itself. The name `initialize` may not appropriate https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html